# Powershell Load-ComboBox with all members from csv

Tags: powershell, csv, combobox

I'm trying to lookup a .csv, return all unique members and update a combobox.

Services.csv eg:

```
ServerName         Service         Description
Server1            Spooler         Print Spooler
Server2            Spooler1        Print Spooler1
Server1            Spooler1        Print Spooler1
```

The below powershell script returns the unique members correctly.

```
$Serverslist = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Scripts\Services.csv" | Select-Object -Property $_.ServerName | select -Unique ServerName | Sort ServerName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
```

When I try to update the Combobox using the below code it only displays the first member.

```
ForEach ($Server in $Serverslist) { Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $comboboxServer -Items $Server -Append}
```

If I remove the below it updates the combobox with correct members but has a 
@{Servername=blablabla}

```
Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `Select -ExpandProperty Servername` instead of `Format-Table`?

Comment: That solved it. You are the best! How do I mark your answer as solution, it doesn't have an option next to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Select -ExpandProperty Servername` instead of `Format-Table`?

Answer (score 0):

I created one .csv file for multiple combo_box, but you can just have one item, my.csv looks like:

```
Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4
House,Blue,Casa,Azul
Car,Red,Carro,Rojo
```

Then at the end of my FORM file:

```
function funlist1() {
    #SET THE LOCATION OF YOUR FILE
    Set-Location **C:\PATH1\PATH2**

    #LOAD YOUR FILE
    $file = Import-Csv ".\**YOUR_FILE**.csv"
        $List = @()
        foreach ($line in $file) {
                $text=$line.Item1+": "+$line.Item2
                $List+=$text
        }
    return $List
}

#THIS WILL LOAD THE ARRAY TO THE COMBO_BOX
funlist1 | ForEach-Object {[void] $COMBO_BOX_NAME.Items.Add($_)}
```